# Most efficient/fastest way to load several hundred SVGs on a website

Tags: performance, svg, google-cloud-firestore, cdn, headless-cms

I have a web app where I want to load several hundred SVGs onto one page.

As of right now I am uploading  them all in Google Firestore after minifying the SVG. I then load them on the webpage and render the SVG as code on the page.

Would they load on the page faster if I upload all the SVGs to a headless CMS or some sort of CDN?

I just want to find the best way to do this so the user doesn't have to wait long for all of the SVGs to load.

Thanks so much for any advice!

Comment: Do you have to have several hundred images on a page? Have you seen pages like that? What is your user going to do with it (if he is patient enough to wait for it to load)? Pagination?

Comment: Yes they will only load ~15 at a time but then they will paginate, maybe I worded the question wrong but I was just curious the best/fastest way to retrieve these SVGs.